# When a person falls from large heights, what is it that causes death?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

Would it be the impact force that kills you? Or would it be the change in momentum? Cause I've gotten conflicting answers when asking this cause if I imagine a scenario where someone falls from great heights into a large pit of polyurethane foam the change in momentum would also be drastic just as if they were to hit concrete but they more than likely wouldn't die. So I personally feel it would have to be the force upon impact from the material or object that you hit that kills you, not the change in momentum as some people I have asked have stated. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is strictly speaking a medical/forensics question with no general answer.  There are even (rare) cases of people falling without a parachute from planes at great heights and surviving.

Answer (score 3):

The force a person experiences when coming to a sudden stop after a fall is determined by how fast they came to a stop.  Newton's 2nd Law, which describes the force experienced by an object, can also be written as

$F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$

This means that for the same momentum change, the force experienced goes up as the time required to change that momentum goes down.  For a person landing on a "soft" target, the time to stop is extended, so the force required to change that person's momentum is small.  Likewise, if the person lands on concrete, the time required to stop the person is very small, the force on that person is very large, and that very large force kills the person as a result

Comment: I'd say that "the force kills you" isn't quite specific enough to answer the question. What is it about the force that creates this causal relationship between force and death?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist, I didn't want to get too graphic in my response.

Comment: You can be descriptive and accurate without being graphic

Answer (score 1):

Broken bones are a good chance at cause of death. If sudden change of momentum breaks all your ribs and the broken bones puncture your lungs, that will probably kill you.

Sudden change of momentum of your brain can do a lot too. Your brain is made largely of fat and it doesn't have a tremendous amount of tensile strength. Say you are face up when you hit, and say that your skull doesn't get broken. Your brain still has to stop very suddenly, and it's the back part of your brain that's stopping the front part. So it gets a lot of pressure back there, that might tear blood vessels and snap neurons. Your cerebellum and brainstem has some functions that have to work for you to stay alive. They get interrupted and there you are, dead.

And if the skull breaks and sharp edges are getting pressed into your brain....

If you fall from a great height onto foam rubber, what distance is it slowing you? If it's a few inches, that won't have much effect. A few feet? For a long fall, that isn't much. Though every little bit helps....

There's a carnival trick where a fat man jumps from a big height -- 20 to 30 feet -- onto a child's swimming pool full of water. He does a belly flop and stands up unharmed. The water almost all splashes out when he lands. I'm not sure about the details, but some of how it works is the water moving out of the way collects a lot of kinetic energy. Another part is the big belly compresses and absorbs some momentum. Those are sort of qualitative explanations, but I can't say I really understand it.

Answer (score 1):

It's the force. If the force is constant during the duration of the impact then

$$
\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t} = F
$$

If someone drops from a fixed height then their momentum at the bottom of the fall is fixed at $p_{max}$ and we are interested in $\Delta p= p_{max}-0$. This means $\Delta p$ is fixed.

If $\Delta t$ is really large, like someone falling one a stretchy rope, or someone falling into pillows or an air cushion or trapeze net, then $\Delta t$ can be made to be really large so that $F$ is small.

If $\Delta t$ is really small, like hitting concrete or something incompressible, then $F$ can be extremely large.

Safety tools like ropes and carabiners are rated for maximum force they can handle without breaking. For example climbing carabiners are typically rated to a maximum force of 20 kN or so. If this force is exceeded the device will undergo some failure mechanism and break.

Humans are the same, if their body is exposed to forces over a certain value then their organs undergo some failure mechanism and break resulting in death. I'm not a doctor and for details on the specific failure mechanism you might look into more medical sources than physics stack exchange but I would guess the problems that arise when exposing the entire body to a large force like in a fall are concussive effects on the brain and perhaps breakages in the circulatory system.

TLDR: excessive forces break things.